# Find the surface area of the solid of revolution obtained by rotating the curve $y=\cos(3x)$ from $x=0$ to $x=\frac\pi6$ about the $x$-axis

Tags: calculus, integration

I tried integrating $y = \cos (3x)$

Then I subtracted the integral evaluated at $0$ from $\frac{\pi}{6}$ and I got

To find the surface area of the solid of revolution obtained by rotating the curve $y = cos(3x)$ from $x = 0$ to $x = \frac{\pi}{6}$ about the $x$-axis, we can use the following formula:

$$S = \int_a^b 2 \pi y \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{d y}{d x} \right)^2} d x$$

where $[a, b]$ is the interval of rotation, $y$ is the function being rotated, and $\frac{d y}{d x}$ is its derivative.
In this case, we have:

$$y = \cos(3x)$$

$$\frac{d y}{d x} = -3 \sin (3 x)$$

So, the surface area of the solid of revolution is:

$$S = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{6} 2 \pi \cos(3 x) \sqrt{1 + (-3 \sin(3 x))^2} dx = 2 \pi \int_0^\frac{\pi}{6} \cos(3 x) \sqrt{1 + 9 \sin^2(3 x)} dx$$

We can evaluate this integral by making the substitution
$u = \sin(3 x)$: $\frac{d u}{d x} = 3 \cos(3 x) \implies dx = \frac{du}{3 \cos(3 x)}$. Using this substitution, we get:

$$\frac{2 \pi}{9} \int_0^{\sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right)} \sqrt{1 + 9 u^2} du$$
$$= \frac{2 \pi}{9} \left[ \frac{1}{2} u \sqrt{1 + 9 u^2} + \frac{1}{3} \ln \left( \sqrt{1 + 9 u^2} + 3 u \right) \right]_0^{\sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right)}$$
$$= \frac{2 \pi}{9} \left[ \frac{1}{2} \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) \sqrt{1 + 9 \sin^2 \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right)} + \frac{1}{3} \ln \left( \sqrt{1 + 9 \sin^2 \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right)} + 3 \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) \right) \right] - \frac{2 \pi}{9} [0]$$
$$= \frac{2 \pi}{9} \left[ \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{3} \ln (\sqrt{2} + 3) \right]$$
$$= \frac{\pi}{3} \sqrt{2} + \frac{2}{9} \ln (\sqrt{2} + 3)$$

Therefore, the surface area of the solid of revolution is

$$\frac{\pi}{3} \sqrt{2} + \frac{2}{9} \ln (\sqrt{2} + 3)$$

Comment: Write this in the body of your question...not in comments

Comment: Just copy paste it...and use latex if possible

Comment: Echoing the previous comment. You can consult the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: After substituting $u=\sin(3x)$, you have a mistake in replacing $dx$ with $du$. This should contribute a factor of $\frac13$, not $\frac19$.$$2\pi\int_0^{\tfrac\pi6} \cos(3x)\sqrt{1+9\sin^2(3x)}\,dx=2\pi \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+9u^2}\cdot\color{red}{\frac13}\,du$$since $du=\color{red}{3}\cos(3x)\,dx$.